# Retrieving multiple counts from a table per row returns incorrect count results

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I am trying to show a list of customers and the number of ratings they've left by type. However the returns from counts are not accurate.

This is happening in SQL Server.

I have put together a representative schema and test data here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97908f3/5

```
select customer.custid, customer.name,
(
  select count(eventid) from event
  where type in ('x', 'y')
  and rating = 'good'
  and event.stayid = stay.stayid
) as 'Goods',
(
  select count(eventid) from event
  where type in ('x', 'y')
  and rating = 'ok'
  and event.stayid = stay.stayid
) as 'OKs',
(
  select count(eventid) from event
  where type in ('x', 'y')
  and rating = 'bad'
  and event.stayid = stay.stayid
) as 'Bads'
from customer, stay
where stay.custid = customer.custid
```

The results show:

```
custid  name    Goods   OKs Bads
1       Jane    1       0   1
2       Alice   1       0   1
```

According to the data, Alice shouldn't have the 1 good review.
I have tried the same query as joins but get the same issue.

What am I doing wrong when I am trying to query the same table for multiple counts per row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using a single query with conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    c.custid,
    c.name,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN e.rating = 'good' THEN 1 END) AS Goods,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN e.rating = 'ok'   THEN 1 END) AS Oks,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN e.rating = 'bad'  THEN 1 END) AS Bads
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN stay s
    ON s.custid = c.custid
LEFT JOIN event e
    ON e.stayid = s.stayid AND
       e.type IN ('x', 'y')
GROUP BY
    c.custid,
    c.name;
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, I am investigating this (taking a while to apply & verify with my actual schema). Certainly a direction I hadn't tried.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I needed that pointer. Thanks for simplifying my query! I still have my original problem but now it's clearer to me that my issue was not what I included in this question but instead to do with how I'm handling the addition of time frames. Thanks for providing me with clarity to see this.

Answer (score 1):

@Beeblebrox, what Tim suggested is correct. Based on that I made a few below changes.

```
Select C.CustId, C.Name,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN E.Rating = 'good' THEN 1 END) AS Goods,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN E.Rating = 'ok'   THEN 1 END) AS Oks,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN E.Rating = 'bad'  THEN 1 END) AS Bads
From Customer C LEFT JOIN Stay S ON S.CustId = C.CustId
LEFT Join Event E On E.CustId = S.CustId And E.Type In ('x', 'y')
Group By C.CustId, C.Name
```

[See the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SVxf.jpg)

Comment: . . As far as I can tell, this answer is pretty equivalent to Tim's (although a bit messier).  You should accept Tim's answer.